# php run actions on a different website

Tags: php, jquery, html

I got a problem, I am building an application that allows users to change data that normally could only be changed in an admin panel. My application filters out all vulnerable data. However when I change the data in my aplication, it must also be updated in the original admin panel. To do this I must upload an xml-file into the admin panel. This currently goes manual, but it must be automated. However I must upload it via the admin panel or else the data wont be updated in this panel. Directly updating it with `file_put_contents` doesn't work sadly.

This piece of code is located on `mydomain.com/system_backup.php`. This is in the admin panel and it requires you to log in with a username and pass before you are able to use it.

```
//The html on this page. system_backup.php
<form action="system_backup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   //Downloads the current xml-file from the server
   <input name="Download" type="submit" class="formbtn" id="download" value="Download configuration">
   //select the xml file from your local system.
   <input name="conffile" type="file" class="formfld" id="conffile" size="40">
   //restore/update the xml-file.
   <input name="Restore" type="submit" class="formbtn" id="restore" value="Restore configuration">
</form>
```

This looks like this.
[image: buttons]

When you open the page in a browser the following login prompt is given with javascript/jquery.
[image: loginprompt]

So is there a way to create an automated script with php, that will log in and update this file using this admin panel? If it is not possible with php, then is it possible in a different language? I will have to run this each night with a cron-job.

Comment: As far as i know, is this not possible in PHP. An language where it is possible i think ( because you can use an `webcontrol`) is C#...

Comment: The login prompt is not shown using JavaScript but it's HTTP Basic Access Authentication. When requesting that resource you thus need to send appropriate headers. You do that using AJAX or maybe server-side, using cURL.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yeah I can access the page using `file_get_contents(http://user:pass@domain.com/system_backup.php);`

Comment: But I don't think it's safe to have those credentials in a public form. Thus I suggest sending that request from the server using cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and quite easy. You just have to figure out the method that your web server is using for authenticating users and send appropriate data in headers (or cookies).

For example, if your server is using [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (and it probably does), you have to add a header to your request, looking like this:

```
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxx is a Base64 of a string: `username:password`.

Comment: `file_get_contents(http://user:pass@domain.com/system_backup.php);` this works, but then I get the thing localy, I need to know how to make php activate those 2 buttons though.

Comment: You can't. PHP runs on the server and has nothing to do with a user prompt in a browser.

Comment: You don't need to "activate" any buttons. Just send appropriate data through POST to the url.

Comment: of course, why didn't I think of that, I guess ill go look into how to do that then.

Comment: Lots of info in the web:
http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post ;
http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/